# Strange behaviour of opening fifo first in parent and then in child

Tags: c, linux, fork, mkfifo

So i have been lately playing with fifo's and forks in C and i am a bit confused. I have the following code running in 2 different devices and i take different results every time.

The code is :

```
#define MAX_BUF 1024
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int fd,rc,bytes_in,pid,status;
  char buf[256];
  struct pollfd fdarray [1];

  mkfifo("out.fifo", 0700);

  if (fork() == 0) {

    fd = open("out.fifo", O_WRONLY, 0);
    printf("fifo opened on child\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

    printf("parent is gonna sleep\n" );
    sleep(10);
    printf("parent woke up\n" );
    fd = open("out.fifo", O_RDONLY, 0);
    printf("fifo opened on father\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

And i run this code in 2 different devices. Both devices run debian 8. The result in each one is the following.

For the first one:

```
parent is gonna sleep
fifo opened on child
parent woke up
fifo opened on father
```

And for the second one

```
parent is gonna sleep
parent woke up
fifo opened on father
fifo opened on child
```

So this seems strange. Normally in both devices it should either wait for parent to woke up or maybe an error should occur because as it is stated in the man page of fifo

```
opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO (no such 
device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.
```

Instead in my device it runs the child process first opening the fifo. On the other device it just waits. Can someone explain me why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong?

**ΕDIT:** Well it might sound weird but today it works right. When i run the exact same code the parent sleeps and the child waits till parent wakes up to open the fifo

Comment: FIFOs are rarely used and therefore buggy, and even their as-specified behavior is bizarre relative to everything else.  You will be happier using "Unix domain" sockets (`man 7 unix`).

Comment: Having said that, you may get _less_ peculiar behavior if you actually write to / read from the FIFO.

Comment: sadly i cannot do eitherwise since it's a part for a project. gonna attempt to read and write to it as you said

Comment: Your output shows the sequencing but not the timing of the outputs. Neither process's `open()`  returns until the other's is called, but thereafter, the sequence depends on the whims of the scheduler; it is not deterministic.

Comment: the message "fifo opened on child" on the first execution is printed instantly and then i wait a couple of seconds since parent woke up

Comment: well it might sound weird but today it works right. When i run the exact same code parent sleep and the child wait till parent wakes up to open the fifo